# Running a Java app with an Access database from the Windows command prompt

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, jdbc-odbc

I have developed a Windows MS Access Java app with Netbeans V6.1 Everything works okay in the IDE including loading the MS Access data into a jTable. When I run it from the Windows command line, the app starts but the data is not loaded into the jTable. Instead, I get pages of errors, but the first few are:

```
java -jar doactions.jar
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Jan 28, 2016 12:22:21 AM doactions.DoActionsView <init>
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

`doActions` is the app and `DoActionsView` is the where the jTable is. It seems that the build does not see the MS Access database defined in the ODBC Manager. Can anyone please offer any help?

Comment: Have your app display the string returned by `System.getProperty("java.version")`. Does it by chance refer to "1.8" (Java 8) when you run it from the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the JDBC ODBC driver jar is in your class path.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I did not see the question from Gord Thompson.

The version of Java whch is displayed at the java prompt and the runtime version of the app is 1.8.0_45 but from the Netbeans IDE is 1.6.0_45. I assume I have somehow installed different versions of run time java and the JDK. As Netbeans is happy to run the 1.6 version, I will firstly reinstall run time 1.6 version to see if this fixes the problem.

I had two versions of java installed on my laptop. I have now removed the 1.8 version and everything works fine. Many thanks

Lawrence

Answer (score 0):

When launching the app from the command prompt it was running under a Java 8 (1.8.0_45) JVM (Java Virtual Machine) and when running the app in NetBeans it was running under Java 6 (1.6.0_45). That explains the difference.

The command-prompt invocation was running under the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) registered with the operating system. Oracle currently distributes Java 8 when you download the JRE from java.com.

NetBeans was running that same application under Java 6 because it was using a Java 6 JDK (Java Development Kit). NetBeans was launching its Java environment from the JDK, not the stand-alone JRE.

As for why the app would work under Java 6 and fail under Java 8, the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8 and is no longer available. For an alternative that *does* work with Java 8, see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)